# What is Camping 'meta_def' doing?

Tags: ruby, camping

In one of the first lines of camping.rb: https://github.com/camping/camping/blob/ae5a9fabfbd02ba2361ad8831c15d723d3740b7e/lib/camping-unabridged.rb#L17,

The framework adds the `meta_def` method to the `Object` class. I've been playing around with this bit of code and I still can't understand what it's doing.

```
class Object #:nodoc:
  def meta_def(m,&b) #:nodoc:
    (class<<self;self end).send(:define_method,m,&b)
  end
end
```

When I try printing `(class<<self;self end)` like this:

```
class Object #:nodoc:
  def meta_def(m,&b) #:nodoc:
    puts (class<<self;self end)
  end
end

puts 'a'.meta_def 'boo'
```

It prints out `#<Class:#<String:0x146810>>`, which means it's making an instance of `Class`.  However, I still don't know what exactly it is and what `(class<<self;self end)` did. Can someone explain how this works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Object 
  def meta_def(m,&b) 
    (class<<self;self end)
  end
end
ob = 'a'
ob.meta_def 'boo' # => #<Class:#<String:0x94daf54>>
ob.singleton_class # => #<Class:#<String:0x94daf54>
```

> I still don't know what exactly it is and what `(class<<self;self end)` did.

Your code is creating the [**`singleton_class`**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Object.html#method-i-singleton_class) of the receiver(`'a'`) of the method `meta_def`.Now look below :

```
class Object #:nodoc:
  def meta_def(m,&b) #:nodoc:
    (class<<self;self end).send(:define_method,m,&b)
  end
end
ob = 'foo'
ob.meta_def(:meth) {"Welcome"}
ob.meth # => "Welcome"
```

> Now in the above code, what the line is doing?

As said above it is creating first a singleton class for the receiver.Then using [**`define_method`**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Module.html#method-i-define_method), a method named `:meth` with a body containing only one line `"Hello"` is created for the receiver singleton class.